# Mark cells in column A that contain text from any cell in column B

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a base set of data in column A and a larger result set in column B that has trash values I don’t need.

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | NBVAAAYHK |
| BBB | GHYCCCJOO |
| CCC | VFBBBHGT |
|  | VFGHUYRCJ |

Similar to the example above with about 300 cells in A and 12k in B. In the example, I want B1-3 marked either by a highlight or a value in C. As long as I can sort and separate the trash.

I’ve tried to use VLOOKUP and MATCH but I can’t get them to work consistently or how I expect them to. And I’m sure an answer to this is out there but I haven’t been able to craft a query to find it. I appreciate your help! Happy to elaborate further if needed.

Comment: What result do you expect in column C from given sample data?

Comment: If the answer results in a value in column C, I would be happy with any 2 values. Like YES for a match in B, or a NO, for instance. The answer could also just be a highlight to the cell in column B. Anything to differentiate a match vs no match

Comment: `BBB` will partial match to 3rd cell of column B. So, will it give yest or no for row 2 of column A.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying, good point. I want the result to relate to Col B, so B3 matching to A2 would give a yes in C3, next to the B cell that matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next version, too. It will write in C:C the matching string. Comma separated if many such matches exist:

```
Sub MarkMatches()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRA As Long, lastRB As Long, arrA, arr, i As Long, j As Long
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastRA = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastRB = ws.Range("B" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRB).ClearContents 'clear C:C column if code has previously been run
 arrA = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRA).Value2
 arr = ws.Range("B2:C" & lastRB).Value2
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(arr(j, 1), arrA(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            If arr(j, 2) = "" Then arr(j, 2) = arrA(i, 1) Else: arr(j, 2) = arr(j, 2) & ", " & arrA(i, 1)
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 'drop the processed array content, at once:
 ws.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arr), 2).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=OR(COUNTIFS(B2,"*"&$A$2:$A$4&"*"))
```

[image]

Comment: This isnt working for me the way you show, its comparing adjacent cells. how does B4 match to A3 in your formula?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 0):

Checking keyword matching with `instr`.

```vb
Sub demod()
    Dim r As Long, i As Long
    Dim rowCntA As Long, rowCntB As Long
    Dim arrA, arrB, arrC()
    arrA = Range([a1], [a1].End(xlDown)).Value
    arrB = Range([b1], [b1].End(xlDown)).Value
    rowCntA = UBound(arrA)
    rowCntB = UBound(arrB)
    ReDim arrC(1 To rowCntB, 0)
    For i = 1 To rowCntB
        arrC(r, 0) = False
        For r = 1 To rowCntA
            If InStr(arrB(i, 1), arrA(r, 1)) > 0 Then
                arrC(r, 0) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    Next i
    Range("C:C").Clear
    [c1].Resize(rowCntB, 1).Value = arrC
End Sub
```